# Changing an index column name of a csv file inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have several `csv` files whose 1st `index` [0] retrieves "Unnamed:0" and I'd like to change this column to "date" inside a `for loop`. The function I created has a for loop that is essentially doing this: 1) retrieving the data I want, 2) turn it into a `dataframe`, 3) change the 1st column from Unnamed:0 to date and 4) turn the `dataframes` into `csv` files to a directory.

This is the code

```
def custom_stock_data (ticker):
    for symbol in ticker:
        ticker_data = pd.DataFrame(get_data(symbol, start_date = "05/25/2021", end_date = "07/30/2021", interval = "1d"))
        ticker_data = ticker_data.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0':'date'}, inplace= True)
        ticker_csv = ticker_data.to_csv(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\estagio\data_{}.csv".format(symbol))
        print(ticker_data)
custom_stock_data(["AMZN"])
```

This is the CSV output:

```
Unnamed: 0     open         high         low          close  

2021-05-25     3266.669922  3279.820068  3213.760010  3259.050049
```

I'm getting two types of errors:

When I execute the function `custom_stock_data` I get an indentation error on the line             `ticker_data = ticker_data.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0':'date'}, inplace= True)` (Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. The tab is automatically created when I press `Enter` from the previous line, so I don't understand why it is giving this indentation error

The 2nd error is after executing the `custom_stock_data("AMZN")`. The terminal retrieves "Local variable 'ticker data' referenced before assignment".

I was hoping that by calling `ticker_data` inside the for loop the 2nd time I could change all the "Unnamed" columns in the dataframe to "date"

Comment: The first error is surely due to your editor. If it's not Python-aware, it probably creates whitespace which doesn't work well with Python. Anyway, try retyping all the whitespace, or if your editor has a command to replace tabs with spaces, try that.

Comment: Anyway, you should focus on one problem per question; otherwise, you will get competing answers which address different parts of your question, none of which probably can be accepted as solving your question adequately.

Comment: Completely removing your data is also problematic; could you please [edit] to include a snippet of your CSV as text?

Comment: `for symbol in ticker` will loop over the individual letters in the string you pass in. You want to call `custom_stock_data(["AMZN"])` if you want to keep that function signature.

Answer (score 0):

Simply passing `index = False` in  `ticker_csv = ticker_data.to_csv(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\estagio\data_{}.csv".format(symbol), index = False)` will do the trick! Fixed